# What could cause an asp.net application to forget a user?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I've got an asp.net application which seems to forget that a user is logged in after a while.

I'm using the membership provider and when opt to "remember" the log in it remembers it during the session.  I can even close the browser, restart and come back and it will still be logged in.  But after a while it forgets and it seems to do it at any old time.  I've once been logged in and when I went to a new page it was logged out.

The other strange things are:

1. On my development machine it remembers the log in forever.  Even after IIS restarts and recompiles it will remember my login as expected.
2. I have another application on the same server that does remember the login forever.  I compared how they handle login and they seem to be identical.

This leads me to believe that the issue has something to do with the server or perhaps something in the application not directly related to the login and membership code.  What could I look at?

Edit:
Looked up the cookie using Fiddler and they seem to be ok.
An Authentication cookie created today expires 2 weeks from now, which is how my config is set up:
expires=Mon, 06-Sep-2010 01:47:51 GMT

Edit:
The problem seems to be that the app pool is recycling and the authentication cookie becomes invalid because it can no longer be read as the machine key has changed.  The solution was to add a machineKey segment to the web.config and supply a static machine key.

Comment: Remember me function is based on cookie. So I would diagnose cookie lifecycle.

Comment: I took a look at the cookie and its expiration is 2 weeks in the future.

Comment: Just one production machine or is it load balanced?

Comment: Yes, it's just 1 server. I'm looking at the app recycle and machine key as recommended by one of the answers.  However, I'm not sure why I'd see this issue on one server but not another.  Both recycle the app pools regularly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major possibilities.

1. Cookie expiration.  If the cookie expires / goes away, then you are considered logged out.
2. Cookie invalidation.  Login cookies are encrypted based on the machineKey value.  If you do not specify a machineKey, a new one is regenerated each time the application pool starts up (or is recycled).  That means that any login cookie encrypted with the old machineKey is now invalid, and you will not be considered logged in.

Check to see what the recycle settings are on your application pool in IIS and see if that corresponds with the timing of you not being logged in.

Comment: I checked the cookie expiration and it seems ok (expires in 2 weeks as expected).  The second item you wrote seems like it could be what I'm seeing.  I guess I should do some reading on login cookies and machinekey.

Comment: Cookie invalidation seems to be the cause.  I added a static machineKey to the web.config and it hasn't forgotten my login yet.

Answer (score 3):

"Remember me" functionality is done using cookies.  Cookies can be set with an expiration date.  You need to look into how the cookie is being set (Fiddler is good for this, you can inspect the HTTP header when the cookie is set.)

Comment: The expiration date seems to be ok.  I'm looking into the machinekey and app pool recycling as another person mentioned.  Seems to be what I'm seeing, but not sure why one app would be affected and another is fine.